# How to Access Host IP Address From AWS Fargate Docker Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, containers, aws-fargate

I am hosting my node app on AWS via Fargate Docker. How can I pass the Fargate's container public IP address to my node.js app?

Fargate only gives the public IP address after my app is deployed, so I can't pass the address to app as ENV variable before my task is running.

My node app has to redirect users to its the applications URL, but I need the public address for that, I believe...

Where can I read more about this?

I am new to AWS and Containers so thank you all for your help in advance!

Comment: " public IP address after my app is deployed" - yes, that's how it works. Not sure what else do you want?

Comment: I want my node.js app to know what the public IP address is. How can my node app access it from the container? E.g. if node wants to redirect user to /home, how can it redirect to IP_ADDRESS/home?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [describe-tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-tasks.html) to obtain the `eniId` and use the `eniID` to obtain the public IP like `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --network-interface-ids eni-xxxxxxxx` 
If you are looking to obtain the public IP from the AWS console, you can follow below steps:

- In order to obtain the public IP from the AWS console, go to ECS service.
- In the left-side navigation pane, choose `Instances & Images > Instances`
- In the top navigation bar, select a `region`
- Find the ECS instance that is under consideration
- There should be an option to view the public IP in there

Comment: Can I do this through the AWS interface website? I am really noob so I haven't hosted anything from the AWS command line yet...

Comment: I would highly encourage to learn on how to setup AWS CLI. Have updated how to view the public IP from the console, haven't verified the steps myself as I would need a cluster up and running for that

Comment: Sorry if I didn't word my question clearly. But my problem is that my node.js app doesn't know what its container IP address is. So when my app redirects the user to IP_ADDRESS/home, node does not know the value of "IP_ADDRESS".

Comment: would redirect to "127.0.0.1/home" automatically redirect the user to "PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS/home"?

Comment: So from your Node App, you can obtain the public IP programmatically

Comment: How is a container supposed to know it's eni?

Answer (score 1):

you can enable [container metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-metadata.html) and look for the `HostPublicIPv4Address` value

example of metadata file inside fargate instance:

```json
{
    "Cluster": "default",
    "ContainerInstanceARN": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:012345678910:container-instance/default/1f73d099-b914-411c-a9ff-81633b7741dd",
    "TaskARN": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:012345678910:task/default/2b88376d-aba3-4950-9ddf-bcb0f388a40c",
    "TaskDefinitionFamily": "console-sample-app-static",
    "TaskDefinitionRevision": "1",
    "ContainerID": "aec2557997f4eed9b280c2efd7afccdcedfda4ac399f7480cae870cfc7e163fd",
    "ContainerName": "simple-app",
    "DockerContainerName": "/ecs-console-sample-app-static-1-simple-app-e4e8e495e8baa5de1a00",
    "ImageID": "sha256:2ae34abc2ed0a22e280d17e13f9c01aaf725688b09b7a1525d1a2750e2c0d1de",
    "ImageName": "httpd:2.4",
    "PortMappings": [
        {
            "ContainerPort": 80,
            "HostPort": 80,
            "BindIp": "0.0.0.0",
            "Protocol": "tcp"
        }
    ],
    "Networks": [
        {
            "NetworkMode": "bridge",
            "IPv4Addresses": [
                "192.0.2.0"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "MetadataFileStatus": "READY",
    "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1b",
    "HostPrivateIPv4Address": "192.0.2.0",
    "HostPublicIPv4Address": "203.0.113.0"
}
```

Comment: This only works for Ec2, not Fargate instances